# How do I extract a word from a pandas dataframe/series using a list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently using str.contain to extract a required word from a series for now. Later deciding to use a dataframe to perform the same.

```
text = pd.Series(['ENTER YOUR PIN NUMBER', 'ORDER READY FOR SHIPPING'])
text.str.contains('PIN', regex=False)
```

Since SHIPPING also has a PIN in it, the Output I got was,

```
True
True
dtype: bool
```

Output Expected,

```
True
False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get if an exact word is in a sentence you should check for the word with spaces before and after it.

```py
def check_word(sentence, word):
    return (' ' + word + ' ') in (' ' + sentence + ' ')

list_validate=[]
for sentences in text:
  list_validate.append(check_word(sentences, 'PIN'))
```

It returns:

```py
[True, False]
```

In order to generalize it for a list of words to check, not only one, you can use

```
def check_word2(sentence,words):
  return any(' ' + word + ' ' in ' '+ sentence+' ' for word in words)
```

Comment: This works. Thank you for the response.How do I perform on list of keywords such as ls = ['PIN','SHOP','ORDER']. Basically it should return TRUE for all these keywords.